# Eclipse kepler loses working sets bindings

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

Have a problem with Eclipse Kepler.
I have a workspace with many projects, organized in many working sets. Projects are located on external USB harddrive. When i've opened workspace with HDD being occidentally detached those projects were in closed  state and many of them(but not all) lost their working set bindings.Reopening workspace with HDD attached didn't help - workspace remains in that broken  state ( projects are closed and working set bindings are lost). So had to manually readd projects to working sets.

Is it some sort of a bug in eclipse or i can avoid this behaviour using some eclipse settings ?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds similar to this Eclipse bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412970 unfortunately that is not much help as it does not look like the bug has been looked at